# Migration from Jenkins to Teamcity

Tags: jenkins, teamcity, ci-server

Suggest me how to migrate all build logs, jobs, config files jenkins to teamcity .
From teamcity to teamcity it is possible, from same CI servers it is possible.. But what are the steps to migrate jenkins to teamcity?

Comment: Welcome to SO please carefully ready http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct upgrade path.
You must manually recreate project, build configurations and steps based on the technology you use.

It's not possible to convert build history, artifacts or other data from Jenkins.